# Operate servo based on AC voltage: solenoid replacement

Tags: microcontroller, servo, solenoid, replacement, substitution

In short, I’m trying to find a substitute for a solenoid in a system that was operating based on 120V. The servo needs to rotate a little shaft about 45 degrees when the voltage comes on, and then rotate it back when the voltage goes off. I don’t want to use another solenoid because it was having to stay on for long periods, and it has now melted for the second time.

If necessary, I can rig something up with a Raspberry Pi, but I’m wondering if there’s a more convenient/compact way to do it. I have a STAMP 2 if that helps, but I’ve never used it, and I can buy other hardware. Okay at soldering, but not that hot (no pun intended.)

Comment: You may be able to find a continuous duty solenoid. It sounds like you were using non continuous duty solenoids. Just a suggestion, not an answer.

Comment: I tried to see if there is any 0-10V analog voltage controlled servos out there, but it seems all the ones you can buy work off of pulse trains. There's this very overpriced pre-programmed microcontroller which does what you want https://www.sparkfun.com/products/13118 , but I think doing it yourself on the STAMP wouldn't be too hard https://forums.parallax.com/discussion/91051/more-about-standard-servo-control-with-the-basic-stamp-2 If you want something smaller, there's the ATTiny based boards like the DigiSpark (programmed in Arduino) that will do the same thing. Also, NE555 based circuits

Comment: @thelabcat, what is your question?

Comment: @VoltageSpike is there a more convenient/compact way to do it? Right now I’ve got a lamp plugged into the solenoid power, pointing at a solar panel, which is wired to the pi 2, which is controlling the servo. Note, I would’ve used a phototransistor instead of a solar panel, but it was what I had on hand.